# App doesn't reduce in size when removing resources from the Copy Bundle Resources phase

Tags: ios, resources, storage

When deploying from Xcode, apps don't seem to change size despite the fact that I remove assets from the copy bundle resources phase and reinstall.  When I make an app store update where I have removed resources from the copy bundle resources phase, will the app reduce in size?

Comment: Are you copying bundle resources to app documents folder and that is what you removed assets from?

Comment: You're not actually allowed to remove resources from the bundle at runtime, right?  I'm just deleting them in Xcode and rebuilding.  Intuitively, I know it should reduce in size upon installation.  I'm basically wondering if the updated app cleans out resources that were removed upon updating, because when installing through Xcode, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yeah if you are unlinking them then it shouldn't copy them in. Are you deleting the app and reinstalling it? Another thing is to just rebuild it with a different bundle id so you can compare them both side by side.

Comment: This is an oft repeated problem. Xcode does its best to merge bundle resources, and if you delete things like a nib file, they often hang around wrecking havoc. What you need to do is in the Organizer window, delete the working folder for the app. Then, delete the app from your phone. Now load it again and the size should be smaller.

Comment: Yeah, I'm purposely not deleting the app before reinstalling to test its behavior when just installed on top of the previous version.  Does this discrepancy occur when updating from the app store as well?